# How to write Vue test cases for Vue method in a component using vue-test-utils and jest which has store dispatch function

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-component, vuex, vue-test-utils

i am writing jest test cases for my vue component
i have a method which calls store dispatch function

```
dismissed() {
      this.$store.dispatch("alert/hideAlert");
},
```

in the test cases i am triggering the dismissed event like below and expecting the store action method to call

```
 wrapper.vm.dismissed();
 await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
 expect(actions.hideAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

but the dismissed method call "wrapper.vm.dismissed();" throws below error while running test cases

**Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined**

How can i test this this vue method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the simplest way to do it.

```js
const mockStore = { dispatch: jest.fn() }
const wrapper = shallowMount(YourComponent, {
   mocks: {
      $store: mockStore
   }
}

wrapper.vm.dismissed();
await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
expect(mockStore.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('alert/hideAlert');
```

But you can also do it in different ways.
[Check this article](https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vuex-in-components-mutations-and-actions.html)